# Категория у глаголов движения, существует ли подобное у других глаголов

Tags: глаголы, аспектология

Смысловая разница у предложений указана в комментариях:

```
Он сейчас бегает. // Не подразумевает направленности, а лишь фокусируется на процессе
Он сейчас бежит.  // Из пункта А в пункт Б

Он сейчас летает. // Не подразумевает направленности, а лишь фокусируется на процессе
Он сейчас летит.  // Из пункта А в пункт Б

Он сейчас плавает. // Не подразумевает направленности, а лишь фокусируется на процессе
Он сейчас плывет.  // Из пункта А в пункт Б
```

Любопытно, как один и тот же по смыслу глагол разделился (морфологически) по какому-то критерию. Это, видимо, произошло потому, что русский язык беден на времена, и то что в английском языке выражается временем, здесь пришлось выражать другим глаголом. Я специально сказал по **какому-то**, потому что хочу поискать похожее грамматическое разделение среди других глаголов, по какому-угодно критерию, по каким угодно лексемам (но не по приставкам).

PS
Кстати, я только что открыл, что так называемая группа глаголов движения, на самом деле не ограничивается глаголами движения. Например

```
Избежи этого
Избеги этого.
Избегай этого
Избегни этого.
```

Тут для начала нужно составить список всех таких глаголов и посмотреть, есть ли там избыточность (как у истинных глаголов движения).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на заданный вопрос "Категория у глаголов движения, существует ли подобное у других глаголов".

Вопрос сформулирован не совсем понятно, поэтому ответ в рамках современной грамматики - нет, не существует. И это не "один и тот же по смыслу" глагол, это разные по семантике глаголы с общим компонентом движения, так называемые однонаправленные - разнонаправленные (или моторно-некратные - моторно-кратные). Всего их в русском языке 15 пар. Они одного вида - несовершенного.

Связи с приведенными примерами императива я не вижу (и императива "избежи" нет). Здесь как раз, в отличие от глаголов движения, деление по виду, с морфологической (не семантической!) вариативностью форм: избегать - избежать/избегнуть/избечь.

Comment: Понятно. Я записал этот вопрос больше для себя как программу на дальнейшие исследования, так что принял ваш ответ авансом и если что-то в дальнейшем найду (что типа не существует), то добавлю ответ и переприму его.

Comment: Вы говорите разные по смыслу. Но в английском нет такого разделения, там обходятся одним по смыслу глаголом, а различие придает уже само время глагола продолженное либо повторяющееся. Я это имел в виду, когда писал одинаковые по смыслу. То есть с точностью до английского времени глаголы одинаковые по смыслу (если в русский добавить 12 английских времен)

Comment: В английском и падежей нет, а в пирахан - числа. Смысл изучать русский с логикой другой знаковой системы ) А если вы ищете языковое универсальное, то надо знать минимум два языка как родные - и сравнивать уже их. В рамках одного языка универсальное вы не найдете.

Comment: Ну добавить 12 времен в русский, кажется, не вызовет никаких проблем. Язык останется точно таким же, только с чуть большими возможностями. Смысл изучать русский в сравнении с английским, на мой взгляд, очень большой. Как минимум английский помогает ставить вопросы, о которых в русском не задумываешься, а потом находишь как русский решает эти вопросы и выводишь закономерности, которые без помощи английского ты бы никогда не догадался отыскать.

Comment: Бгг. Удачи с коктейлем!

Answer (score 0):

Если взять какой-нибудь глагол в русском языке, то у него будет как минимум два значения, – например, если взять предложение ‟Я играю в теннис”, то у глагола ‟играю” может быть два значения: значение регулярного выполнения действия (если в контексте у человека нет в руках ракетки, он с кем-то беседует и собеседник понимает, что имеется ввиду регулярное выполнение некого действия), значение выполнения действия в некий момент времени (если вам звонит кто-то, вы играете в теннис и говорите это предложение). Как вы правильно заметили, в английском языке эти отличия не понимаются по контексту, а там эти отличия отображаются изменением формы слова (play – playing). Но в некоторых глаголах в русском языке эти отличия показываются морфемкой на конце слова, как у глаголов движения, или у ‟избегай”, или ещё у каких-то других. Но грамматической категорией и другой формой это не считается, так как что считать грамматической категорией и другой формой – это строгая договорённость, то есть глаголы ‟летать” и ‟лететь” – это родственные слова, у которых по одному значению такого типа: у ‟лететь” – значение выполнения действия в некий момент времени, у ‟летать” – значение регулярного выполнения действия.
Да, и тенсы в английском – это не времена: тенс – это конфигурация глагола, где время только один из нескольких параметров. Например, вышеописанное в этом ответе – это другой параметр тенса, помимо времени.